# Three models Nested Attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 3 models, I named it as `Country, Province, Municipality` and `Country` is under `Province` and `Municipality` is under `Province`. So I make my nested form like this:

My models:

Country

```
has_one :province, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :province
```

Province

```
belongs_to :country
has_many :municipalities, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :municipalities
```

Municipality

```
belongs_to :province
```

My plan should be `@country.province.municipalities.build`. But when I do:

```
@country = Country.new
@country.province.build
```

I've got ``` NoMethodError: undefined method ``build' for nil:NilClass ```.

UPDATE:

I changed my `Country` model with:

```
has_many :provice, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :provinces
```

Then, I've got what I want:

```
@province = @country.provinces.build
@province.municipalities.build
```

is now working. But the problem is when I look at my view, it looks like:

```
country[provinces_attributes][municipalities_attributes][name]
```

which must be:

```
country[provinces_attributes][municipalities_attributes][0][name]
```

What I am missing right here, losing `[0]`?

UPDATE 2

In my views:

```
<%= form_for @country, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :province_attributes do |p| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :municipalities_attributes do |m| %>
      <%= m.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am expecting the text_field name should be `country[province][municipalities][0][name]` but it output without `[0]`, `country[province][municipalities][name]`. What is my error right here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> My plan should be @country.province.municipalities.build. But when I
>   do:
>
> @country = Country.new @country.province.build I've got NoMethodError:
>   undefined method ``build' for nil:NilClass

When you have:

```
has_one :province, dependent: :destroy
```

ActiveRecord will return **nil** if there is no record. When you try:

```
@province = @country.province.build
```

After calling **province** on **@country** you get nil and thus **NoMethodError: undefined method ``build' for nil:NilClass**

Instead just use:

```
@province = @country.build_province
```

This approach is only valid for **has_one** associations

You don't need to do this in the case of **has_many** associations, because when you want to build a new instance of has_many (like you are doing here):

```
@country.provinces.build
```

ActiveRecord will return an empty instance of ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy (which is in fact a rails-enhanced version of an [] - an empty array). CollectionProxy has the **build** method implemented, unlike **nil** in the case of a has_one association.

Comment: what should I do to make country[provinces_attributes][municipalities_attributes][name] to country[provinces_attributes][municipalities_attributes][0][name]? I'll added `UPDATE 2` above for my views.

Comment: Forget about my previous comment. I've got now a solution.